# Prestashop - How to edit views

Tags: php, css, sql, prestashop, prestashop-1.5

How do I edit pages styles in prestashop ? Do I have to do it manually in the template's CSS, and .tpl, or with prestashop admin ?

Comment: "I have a good experience as a web dev" doesn't match with the questions you've made later. Anyway, this question isn't a good question because: 1. it contains many questions (i count 5 of them at least) instead of just one; 2. you are expected to know a minimal understanding of the problem being solved, because right now you seem to have much deeper problems that prestashop (how to access a remote database OR build a local db from a dump, how to change the CSS of a page, either locally, with a linked CSS or through a custom User Interface).

Comment: What I'd save of this message is the last one: "How do I edit a template's CSS in prestashop? Do I have to edit the files directly or is there a panel in the admin section"?

Comment: @STTLCU I was asking where do I find the DB dump, and where are the conf files.

Comment: Sorry for the initial confusion. I edited the question. Could you please remove your negative marks ?

Comment: Here, I've removed it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't edit any files of prestashop at admin. So to edit css files, and .tpl file you have to do it in an editor like DreamWeaver or notepad++ directly. Open the file and edit your required contents in the editor.